# Russian puppets displayproblem with Firefox and Webkit: works well with IE

Tags: javascript, firefox, button, webkit

I have a teaching web page where, in a particular section (DIV), a series of Questions must appear one after another. Once the user answer Q1, then Q2 is shown just below, etc.

Here is the structure:

Mother_DIV contains:
  Text with question and a Button1

DIV2 as display=none which contains: 
    answer to question above + text and a Button2

```
DIV3  as display=none which contains: 
Answer to question above + text and a Button3
```

And so on if needed.

There is a js show(element) function that changes the display style of any element to "inline"
Each button must change the display of the foillowing DIV to inline.

Buttton 1 has: onclick=show('DIV2')
And now when DIV2 is visible, Button2 is visible too

Buttton 2 has: onclick=show('DIV3')
And now when DIV3 is visible, Button3 is visible too...

The script works like a charm on IE9.

On Firefox or Webkit browsers, things get hectic!

Button1 works and DIV2 is shown, but then, Button2 is NOT recognized as a button! Clicking has no effect, and mouse hovering doesn't change the pointer to a hand.

In order to fix it, I changed the structure:

Mother_DIV contains:
  Button1 and Button2 and Button3 etc.
  Plus some text

DIV2 as display=none which contains: 
    text

```
DIV3  as display=none which contains: 
text
```

Guess what: all buttons are now working, each successive DIV being displayed with its text chunk!

The only issue is that this UI is not acceptable, because when the text is too long and user scrolls down, the buttons are no more in the visible part of the page.

Wouls someoe have an idea how to process and save my day?

Comment: What about some code and the actual html structure? Or an example with the actual problem (jsfiddle.net) to play with.

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript show function, try setting the display style to either `'block'` or `''`.
(`'block'` is the default for `DIV` tags, and `''` sets it to the default.)

Answer (score 0):

Founr it! You know what? it is a strange behavior and maybe the answer can be of use to you:

I have a DIV height=500px. That DIV contains 2 sub-DIVs: The 1st one is 490px height top=0.
The second is height=240px AND top=250px (roughly the half bottom part of the main DIV).

The second sub-DIV has display=none unless it is needed. Therefore it is NOT visible.

With IE that is fine.
With other browsers, invisible means invisible to your eyes only, but NOT to the mouse pointer.

Then when a button sits behind the bottom half of the main DIV, it becomes inactive.

Don't vote <0 please!